# How to mock Bean that makes rest api request in spock test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spock, spring-bean

So I have the application which makes a rest api request and I added bean annotation as follows

```java
@Configuratin
public class RequestService {
  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
  @Autowired
  JwtService jwtService;
  
  @Bean
  List<String> getInvalidProduct() {
    String jwt_access_token = this.jwtService.requestToken();
    URI uri = new URI("https://localhost:8080");
    ResponseEntity<?> response = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, this.jwtService.helper(jwt_access_token), Product[].class);
    return response.getBody();
  }
}
```

everything works so far.
However, I am having trouble making spock test. Since this gets registered as soon as application runs, after adding this block of code, it breaks all my previous spock test, which is totally understandable.

Without running `jwtService.requestToken()` or `this.restTemplate.exchange()`, how can I mock this bean and inject the `List<String>` object? Thank you so much in advance

I am trying to make a config class or spocks test as follows

```java
@Configuration
class TestConfiguration {
  @SpringBean
  List<String> getInvalidProduct() {
    List<String> invalids = new ArrayList();
    invalids.add("AAA");
    invalids.add("BBB");
    invalids.add("CCC");
    return invalids;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to replace a bean like this?

Comment: What funny kind of bean definition is `@Bean List<String> getInvalidProduct()` meant to be? How would such a bean even be fetched from the application context? I can only imagine something like `@Bean(name = "invalidProduct") List<String> getInvalidProduct()` and then `List<String> invalidProduct = (List<String>) context.getBean("invalidProduct")`. But still, what would be the point of such a (singleton!) bean? Is the method not supposed to return a dynamic request result? First answer that question, before we think about how to mock such a funny "bean" later.

Comment: And why would you define a `@Bean` factory method inside a `@Service` and not in a `@Configuration` class? Even if it works like that technically, it looks super weird.

Comment: @kriegaex thank you for the comment. I have switched to Configuration annotation.
If I have to make a request upon the server startup (only once), then what other approach would not look super weird? I thought of making bean like this and access what the method returns throughout the application is very handy

Comment: It would not look super weird to create a separate `@Component` class wrapping that piece of logic. Then you could also refer to a class or interface name by convention - `MyComponent` → `getBean("myComponent")` or `getBean(MyComponent.class)` - when instantiating the component. A type like `List<String>` without explicit naming the bean does not easily translate to a default bean name. And what if you need another singleton which also yields a list of strings? Just encapsulate it, would be my two cents.

Comment: You could also mark it as a lazy bean.

Comment: @user16358266 do you mean using lazy annotation? How does it help mocking the bean? Can you elaborate your more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@SpringBean` to create a mock. It is a Spock annotation, so it must be used in a `Specification` and does nothing when used in a `@Configuration` class like you tried.

```
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import spock.lang.Specification

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

@Configuration
class FooConfiguration {

  @Bean
  List<String> getInvalidProduct() {
    List<String> invalids = new ArrayList();
    invalids.add("AAA");
    invalids.add("BBB");
    invalids.add("CCC");
    return invalids;
  }
  @Bean
  List<Integer> getInvalidProductIds() {
    List<String> invalids = new ArrayList();
    invalids.add(1);
    invalids.add(2);
    invalids.add(3);
    return invalids;
  }
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = [FooConfiguration])
class Foo extends Specification {
  @SpringBean
  List<String> invalidProduct = Mock()

  @Autowired
  List<String> injected

  def "test"() {
    when:
    def result = injected.get(1)

    then:
    1 * invalidProduct.get(1) >> "FOO"
    result == "FOO"
  }
}
```

That being said, I agree with @kriegaex that it would be better to wrap this in a service that encapsulates this. You could use the service should probably use application events to defer loading the data until the app is actually started as well.